# Single expression cron scheduler to schedule week days and week ends

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a quartz job in my camel router. The requirement is to have one schedule for Mon-Fri and another for Sat-Sun. I am trying to schedule using single expression.

```
from("quartz://myTimerName1?cron=0 00 06 ? * MON-FRI")
from("quartz://myTimerName2?cron=0 00 11 ? * SAT-SUN")
```

Currently I am doing this by starting it as 2 routes. Just wanted to check if it can be achieved in single route.

Thanks

Comment: The title of this question says something about server timezone, but that is not in your question.

Comment: My bad. I have updated the title now

Comment: @Rajesh if you've figured out how to do this, please post the answer!